# How to exclude compilerOptions for node_modules?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsconfig

I am wondering if it is possible to exclude library folders like *node_modules* from **compilerOptions**.

I want to activate **strictNullChecks**, but there are issues with some libraries f.e. Angular2.

Is there any way to ignore issues in node_modules with compilerOptions?

Comment: `skipLibCheck` is probably what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39917362/6680611

Comment: Yes looks like that, thanks.