# How to disable/suppress errors from libraries in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors

I have turned on some compiler switches to report more issues in code (e.g. strict null checks). But I get tens of errors in used libraries, e.g.:

```
[default] xxx/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/decorators.d.ts:11:5
    Property 'extends' of type 'Type<any> | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'Function | any[] | Type<any>'.
```

Is there any way of suppressing/muting/disabling error checking in libraries (e.g. directory `node_modules`)?

---

It can't be a duplicate of [Allow implicit any only for definition files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38656955/1017211) because my question is much broader. I am not asking how to disable **one** specific check (`noImplicitAny`) in libraries, but how to disable **all** checks in libraries. However the answer from that question applies to mine as well - `"skipLibCheck": true` disables all checks in libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow implicit any only for definition files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656955/allow-implicit-any-only-for-definition-files)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

While this question is not a duplicate of [Allow implicit any only for definition files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38656955/1017211) the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39917362/1017211 from over there does solve my issue.

Edit `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have set `skipLibCheck: true` but I have ts errors in one library. The only lib that I have installed directly from github (the rest is coming from the standard npm repo). Any idea why skipLibCheck does not work here?