# How to opt out of declaration files of a library?

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

Saying that I am using a library like this:
import {Button, Text, Input} from "Lib";

It is written in JS and recently added d.ts to expose types.
The problem is that there are some mistakes, for example in "Input" types.

1. Can I make the compiler ignore only "Input" types?
2. Can I make the compiler ignore all of the library types?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable/suppress errors from libraries in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262513/how-to-disable-suppress-errors-from-libraries-in-typescript)

Comment: You can overwrite the typings https://stackoverflow.com/a/55869760/4467208

Comment: @JimmySmith nope

Comment: @Murat Karagöz it did not override it